# I want run a function without hanging program for second

Tags: java, android, multithreading

when i run

```
msgcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(msgcheck.isChecked()){
                //hedearMsg


                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custommsg);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();

                Thread t = new Thread() {
                  public void run() {
                     // Do something on another thread
                      PopulatePeopleList();

                  }
                };
                t.run();

        }
    });
```

my program hang a few second and then show dialog
i want run this dialog without hanging and PopulatePeopleListfunc work anyone idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are started with `start`, not `run`:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // Do something on another thread
        PopulatePeopleList();
    }
};
t.start();
```

`run` will just call the `run` method sequentially on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

A third option would be to use a `Runnable`, which can be constructed within the thread, or elsewhere:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        PopulatePeopleList();
    }

}).start();
```